# Mongo return [object Object] when try to save an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm trying to save some sort of a comment in an array. The array has two values the username and the comment itself but when I try to save, it always returns [object Object].

The first method I tried was to save the comments

```
// Add the new comment to the blog post's array
                    lesson.comments.push({
                      comment: req.body.comment, // Comment field
                      commentator: user.username // Person who commented
                    });
```

and if there is a problem

```
// Save blog post
                    lesson.save((err) => {
                      // Check if error was found
                      if (err) {
                        res.json({ success: false, message: err }); // Return error message
                      } else {
                        res.json({ success: true, message: 'Comment saved' }); // Return success message
                      }
                    });
```

but that didn't work

then I tried changing the way with the `findByIdAndUpdate`

```
Lesson.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id,
                   {
                     $push: {
                     "comments.comment":req.body.comment,
                     "comments.commentator": req.body.id
                   }
                   },
                   {
                     new:true
                   },
                   function(err,course){
                     if(err){
                       res.json({success:false, message:err});
                       console.log(req);
                     }else{

                       res.json({success:true, message:req.body.comment});
                       //res.json({user});
                     }
                   }
                 )
                 }
```

but I couldn't find the problem

Everything looks alright

Comment: Could you please remove all unrelated to the issue code (e.g. validation).
And try to rewrite this using promises - you just showed a classic example of `callback-hell`. I have a doubt that someone will have a willing to read this spaghetti-code...
Rewriting the code using promises itself could reveal the core of the issue...

Comment: Oh boy, you really need to structure your code better, it's really hard to read as a big clump like that.  Can you break some of those If/Else's out into functions that handle the if/else logic?

Comment: sorry about that I tried to make it clear as much as i could

Comment: and where do you see `[object Object]`?

Comment: In the `err` message